# NetBeans jQuery Autocomplete Not Working

Tags: jquery, netbeans, autocomplete

Autocomplete for jQuery works in my NetBeans on my Mac but not on my PC. Any ideas? Using NetBeans 6.7.1.

Answer (score 1):

Once and for all for everyone who get's here from google or something... It took me some time to figure this out. These is how you make it work:

1. In your code you have something like

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Go to [jQuery Download page](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery)
3. In the same directory where jquery-1.4.2.min.js is (in this case "javascripts")

you drop

the file http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js under Google Ajax API CDN

or

the file http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js under Microsoft CDN.

Thats all! Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

what kind of project are you working on? Seems like netbeans IDE supports jquery autocomplete for php projects but not for python projects. might that be the case here? are you trying to open same projects?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the page: [Jquery Code Snippet](http://www.depcore.com/posts/7-code-snippet-for-jquery-plugin)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you configured your Mac and your PC differently.

Comment: why are poeple downvoting this. the OP doesnt provide any useful information in his question either

Comment: Everything looks correct. Problem solved after NetBEans 6.8 was released.